# How to use 'not in' query for Oracle SQL and Microsoft SQL

Tags: c#, oracle

I have two databases in which iam working. Oracle SQL and Microsoft SQL. I want to select only those values in oracle database which are not exists in sql server table (based on one common columns in both databases). My query is following

```
select instr_no from oracle.table where instr_no not in (select instr_no from microsoft.table where createdby is not null)
```

In c# i have created datatable and store sql server tables values in datatable. Now how can i select only those oracle table values which are not exists in this datatable(based on sql server table), Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have done it using the following query:

```
 var myvar = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("instr_no")).Except(dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("instr_no")));
```

Above is working very nicely. There is one issue that i need to convert myvar variable again into datatable. Please guide, thanks.

Comment: You wanna do a query, or linq? And the two DB are in the same system?

Comment: Two DB's are on different servers. plain SQL server query was best in my scenario but giving the connection string to each query cannot be done in the same sql, so i decide to write and fill datatable and then search from oracle table which are not in this datatabe(based on sql server data), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, making the diference between your tables

```
var idsNotInB = oracle.table.AsEnumerable()
        .Except(microsoft.table.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(m => m.createdby != null));
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe this can help you too [Comparing data from two data tables](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/comparing-data-from-two-data-tables)

Comment: I am almost near to the solution. Please see EDIT in my original question, thanks.